# How to split a routes.js that grows too large to be easily maintained?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, code-organization

I'm using node and express to create a rest api. I followed a tutorial where all the routes and its logic are saved in a `routes.js` file like this:

SERVER JS:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

(...)

require('./app/routes.js')(app, port, express);
```

ROUTES.JS

```
module.exports = function(app, port, express) {


  var apiRoutes = express.Router(); 

(...)

//Sample route 

  apiRoutes.get('/userfiles', function(req, res) {
    UserFile.find({ owner: req.decoded.user.email }, function(err, filesList) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);
      res.json({ success: true, files: filesList });
    });
  });
```

My problem is twofold:

1 - Routes can easily contain code thats 150 lines long, some of them far longer. It doesn't feel clean to have route declarations and the logic grouped together. Is it a good practice to do something like this instead?

```
apiRoutes.post('/randomRoute', function(req, res) {
    return res.json(functionThatContainsTheActualCode(req));
  });
```

(and then have an functionThatContainsTheActualCode function with all the logic in a different file).

2 - I have middleware that applies to some functions (for example, some routes are only accessible for logged in users and those routes go through an authentication middleware). Currently way I do it is declaring public routes before the middleware declaration and private routes after, which feels incredibly hacky. How can I separate public and private routes (and the middleware itself) in different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

We need to go deeper.

Change the route file to just require the actual router logic.

routes.js

```
// where app = express();
module.exports = (app) => {
    // index.js happens to be a file exporting the router.
    app.use('/', require('./index')); 

    // this is basically the idea. Create a separate file for the actual logic.
    app.use('/route', require('.path/to/file'));
};
```

and in file.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    router    = express.Router();

router.verb('/path/', (req, res, next) => {
   // do whatever
});

// this is required
module.exports = router;
```

Problem 2:
Middleware is basically a function taking in `request, response, next` as 3 params, doing something with the `request` and either sending out a `response` or moving on to the next middleware. That's why you need to call `next` if you want to move to next middleware in the chain.

Now all you need is a file that exports a function which takes `request, response, next` as params.
    // lets call this auth.js
    module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

```
    // do logic

    if () {
        return res.send(); // or res.somethingThatSendsOutAHttpResponse() 
    }

   // next middelware
    next();
};
```

Since express routes are also middlewares, (mind blown), you can mount them top down.
To authenticate a route, just put the `auth.js` middleware on top of that route.

```
router.get('/', require('./auth'));
router.get('/', require('./log'));
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    // yolo
});
```

Now since this is web dev, you still got problems. 
Now all your boring database queries are scattered everywhere.
Fear not, you can solve it, by, guess, creating another file.

```
apiRoutes.get('/userfiles', function(req, res) {
    const userFile = require('/path/to/model/with/userfile/methods/exported/out');

    // do something with userFile's methods
  });
```

Comment: Can checkout github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap. It's an complete example of what i wrote above.

Comment: Thanks for that response! I'll try to implement it that way. Excuse my ignorance, but what does the sintax module.exports = (app) => { mean? Is it different from module.exports = function(app){ in any way?

Comment: My bad. Its equivalent to `module.exports = function (app) {  app.use('/', require('./index')); 
 }`

Comment: thanks, that has been extremely useful. One last question, please: What if I need my middleware to use some variables from other files? Like a constant defined in routes.js for example or any other kind of data. Is there any way to pass parameters to the middleware ? Or is it only able to receive (req,res,next)? And if so what is a workaround for that?

Comment: You can add data to the `request` itself. Can set `request._data = {}`  in the server/app.js and use that in all middlewares. Or set data in `response.locals`